# Scanner with System.in not working in CentOS

Tags: java, ubuntu, centos, java.util.scanner

I have 2 computers, one running Ubuntu (desktop) (Java 1.8.0_66) and one running CentOS (command-line only) (Java 1.8.0_72). The following code works on my Ubuntu computer but not on the other one.

```
public class Keyboard implements Runnable {

    final private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void init() {
        new Thread(new Keyboard()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Input.write(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

When I type something on the CentOS computer and hit enter, nothing happens. While on my Ubuntu computer, the String is sent to the Input class.

What I've tried:
Using scanner.next() instead of scanner.nextLine().

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version of java on both computers? What are they?

Comment: In what way *does it not work*?

Comment: @BitNinja Both are running java 1.8.0

Comment: @ElliottFrisch When I type something on the CentOS computer and hit enter, nothing happens. While on my Ubuntu computer, the String is sent to the Input class.